# Read custom heroku domain at runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, environment-variables

Curious if anyone knows a way to access the output of `heroku domains` from an (Rails) app at runtime. I'd like a way to determine the preferred url of a site, programmatically and outside of the request-response cycle, without requiring additional config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Thomas, it doesn't appear to be possible without the API. Solved my particular problem with a setting in the DB rather than an env var.

Answer (score 1):

The Heroku API has an endpoint for [getting and setting domains](https://api-docs.heroku.com/domains). You need your API key to authenticate, and this you should store once in your config environment (not inside the git repo).

Comment: Thanks. My goal was to avoid requiring additional config, but it doesn't seem possible. If I've got to configure something, I might as well make it the domain & skip the API hit.